# Getting CPU name and data using WMI vs using Environment

Tags: c#, environment-variables, wmi

when I am printing

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"));
```

I get

```
AMD64
```

When I am printing

```
var cpu = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Processor").
          Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().First();
wmiValues.Add("cpuName",cpu["Name"].ToString());
```

I get

```
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7500  @ 2.93GHz
```

How is it AMD and Intel ? why is the result different when using WMI vs using Environment

Comment: Do you know what the processor of the computer actually is?  Is one of the answers correct or are they both wrong?

Comment: I think this is just the generic name for 64bit processors that windows uses. probably some legacy from AMD being first. just means it is 64bit. the WMI processor info tells you what the chip actually is.

Comment: Your first command looks to be checking the value of this registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE. As mentioned by @SmithMart this looks to be describing a x64bit enabled processor type. Read this Microsoft [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274%28VS.85%29.aspx)